# Is it possible to do nested if in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do anything like:

```
CASE WHEN name = 'John'
   THEN
    CASE WHEN surname = 'BBBB' THEN XYZ END AS surname
    CASE WHEN surname = 'CCCC' THEN XYZXYZ END AS second_surname
   ELSE
    CASE WHEN surname  = 'BBBB' THEN ABCDEF END AS third_surname
    CASE WHEN surname  = 'CCCC' THEN ABCDEFABCDEF END AS fourth_surname
   END,
```

But I become the error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

How have I to solve this?

Comment: Please give a [MCVE] including some sample data and your expected output for that sample data so we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is your incorrect use of aliases.  The outer `CASE` expression represents one single scalar, so the final outer `END` takes a single alias, and everything inside should not be aliased.  So you may try this version:

```
CASE WHEN name = 'John'
     THEN
         CASE WHEN surname = 'BBBB' THEN XYZ
              WHEN surname = 'CCCC' THEN XYZXYZ END
     ELSE
         CASE WHEN surname = 'BBBB' THEN ABCDEF 
              WHEN surname = 'CCCC' THEN ABCDEFABCDEF END
END AS some_alias
```

But, you could also express your logic using a single level `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN name = 'John'  AND surname = 'BBBB' THEN XYZ
     WHEN name = 'John'  AND surname = 'CCCC' THEN XYZXYZ
     WHEN (name <> 'John' OR name IS NULL) AND surname = 'BBBB' THEN ABCDEF
     WHEN (name <> 'John' OR name IS NULL) AND surname = 'CCCC' THEN ABCDEFABCDEF END AS some_alias
```

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th cases in the second query are not equivalent to the OP's code as `NULL <> 'John'` is not true.

Comment: @MT0 I get it now.  When the `name` be `NULL`, the inequality comparison would fail, but logically we want it to pass, since we know that if the `name` is `NULL`, then it can't possibly be John.

Answer (score 3):

They are all different columns so you need a CASE for each one.

```
CASE WHEN name = 'John' AND surname = 'BBBB' THEN XYZ END AS surname
CASE WHEN name = 'John' AND surname = 'CCCC' THEN XYZXYZ END AS second_surname
CASE WHEN name <> 'John' AND surname  = 'BBBB' THEN ABCDEF END AS third_surname
CASE WHEN name <> 'John' AND surname  = 'CCCC' THEN ABCDEFABCDEF END AS fourth_surname
```

If you want one column then something like @TimBiegeleisen answer will work.

As @MTO points out mine does not handle nulls.  This would solve that

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(name,'Not John') <> 'John' AND surname  = 'BBBB' THEN ABCDEF END AS third_surname
CASE WHEN COALESCE(name,'Not John') <> 'John' AND surname  = 'CCCC' THEN ABCDEFABCDEF END AS fourth_surname
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- maybe -- we don't know what the OP actually wants.  Probably your answer or mine, maybe something else.

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th cases are not equivalent to the OP's code as `NULL <> 'John'` is not true.

Comment: In Oracle an empty string is equivalent to `NULL` so your `COALESCE( name, '' )` is the same as `COALESCE( name, NULL )` and does not do what you are expecting. `WHEN ( name <> 'John' OR name IS NULL ) AND ...` would fix it.